# Entity Framework Core and SQL Server 2016 temporal tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

We are using EF Core and SQL Server 2016 for our .NET Core Web API. I am evaluating use of temporal tables and its impact on EF Core code. When I generate the EF model using cmdline then it generates model with appstart, append and mappings in `dbcontext`. When I do insert/update they fail saying these columns cannot be updated. I had to remove appstart, end from model and `dbcontext` mapping to make it work. I read there is no interception capability yet in EF Core like EF 6.x.

Please advise about any better solutions for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried below options and they are working.

1. option 1: removed appstart, append fields from entities and
   dbcontext mappings and updates/insert started working properly.
2. option 2: decorate period columns with
   attributes as below.

---

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

There currently is no better solution for this, and the feature is on the [backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2229).

Comment: Any solution to bypass the 'GENERATED ALWAYS' columns during INSERT/UPDATE  in database first approach. ? I generate models using DBScaffold command and I cannot use the solution that is marked as answer here as everything gets overwritten each time I generate the model from database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654609/error-when-inserting-into-temporal-table-using-entity-framework-core-2-1

Comment: this should be as a comment, no as a solution, in fact there is a solution

Answer (score 0):

Making the Period start column(StartTime) and Period end column(EndTime) hidden should fix this issue. We can do this by

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ALTER COLUMN [StartTime] ADD HIDDEN;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ALTER COLUMN [EndTime] ADD HIDDEN;
```

We can see the settings for hidden against these columns in the sys.columns table

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE is_hidden = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better solution for this as follows:
Create partial context file (to prevent re-making the changes after re-generating the model) as follows

```
public partial class DatabaseDBContext : DbContext
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.StartTime)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            entity.Property(e => e.EndTime)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 and Entity Framework Core 6.0 supports SQL Server temporal tables out of the box.

See this answer for examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70017768/3850405