# Net Core: Entity Framework and SQL Server Temporal Tables, Automatic Scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

We are having issues using Entity Framework Core 2.2 with SQL Server temporal SystemVersioningTables.

The following  resolve issues with Entity Framework and system versioning columns. [entityframework core and sql 2016 temporal tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627585/entityframework-core-and-sql-2016-temporal-tables)

Using the solution, is there a way for Entity Framework Core 2.2 to automatically add `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` or `OnModelCreating` on SystemVersioning columns?

Is there a command parameter in `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` ?

We are seeking a way to automatically add this in, during automatic database scaffolding. This way, we don't have to manually add this in for all our 1000+ tables, or anytime we add new ones.

Company has many databases.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

or

```
public partial class DatabaseDBContext : DbContext
{
    partial void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.StartTime)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            entity.Property(e => e.EndTime)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
        });
    }
}
```

We're using .NET Core 2.2.

**Note**: we do not want to hide the SQL Server columns, given as third solution in article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OnModelCreating you can examine and modify the model.  So this is as easy as:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var prop in et.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name == "StartTime"|| prop.Name == "EndTime")
            {
                prop.ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is for EF Core 3.1.  EF Core 2.2 is out of support.  2.1 is an LTS branch, as is 3.1.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-2-will-reach-end-of-life-on-december-23-2019/

Comment: that's great, unfortunately I am using EF 2.2,  you said 2.1 is an LTS Branch? do you think they will bring that functionality to 2.2 eventually with LTS?

Comment: 2.2 is gets no fixes or enhancements.  You can do the same thing in 2.2.  The syntax might just be a bit different.

Comment: hi David, maybe you can answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445608/c-entity-framework-fromsql-work-better-with-views-or-stored-procedures

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Why is it `ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate` and not `ValueGenerated.OnAdd` ? Or would both do the same?

Answer (score 2):

.NET 6 and Entity Framework Core 6.0 supports SQL Server temporal tables out of the box.

Usage:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

using IsTemporal:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Customer>()
        .ToTable("Customers", b => b.IsTemporal());

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Product>()
        .ToTable("Products", b => b.IsTemporal());

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Order>()
        .ToTable("Orders", b => b.IsTemporal());
}
```

Querying historical data:

```
var productSnapshots = context.Products
    .TemporalBetween(from, to)
    .OrderBy(product => EF.Property<DateTime>(product, "PeriodStart"))
    .Where(product => product.Name == productName)
    .Select(product =>
        new
        {
            Product = product,
            PeriodStart = EF.Property<DateTime>(product, "PeriodStart"),
            PeriodEnd = EF.Property<DateTime>(product, "PeriodEnd")
        })
    .ToList();
```

Finding a specific historical record

```
var order = context.Orders
    .TemporalAsOf(on)
    .Include(e => e.Product)
    .Include(e => e.Customer)
    .Single(order =>
        order.Customer.Name == customerName
        && order.OrderDate > on.Date
        && order.OrderDate < on.Date.AddDays(1));
```

Restoring deleted data

```
var customerDeletedOn = context.Customers
    .TemporalAll()
    .Where(customer => customer.Name == customerName)
    .OrderBy(customer => EF.Property<DateTime>(customer, "PeriodEnd"))
    .Select(customer => EF.Property<DateTime>(customer, "PeriodEnd"))
    .Last();

var customerAndOrders = context.Customers
    .TemporalAsOf(customerDeletedOn.AddMilliseconds(-1))
    .Include(e => e.Orders)
    .Single();

context.Add(customerAndOrders);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Sources:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/plan

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4693