# EF Core 6.0 temporal tables - Add-Migration - Period property 'Comment.PeriodStart' must be a shadow property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

We have recently upgraded our project to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0`. This release enables SQL Server temporal tables out of the box.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70017768/3850405

We have used temporal tables since Entity Framework Core 3.1 using custom migrations as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776658/3850405

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64244548/3850405

Simply following Microsofts guide will of course not work since default column names are `PeriodStart` and `PeriodEnd` instead of our `SysStartTime` and `SysEndTime`. History table name does not match either.

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Comment>()
    .ToTable("Comments", b => b.IsTemporal());
```

Migration created:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AlterTable(
        name: "Comments")
        .Annotation("SqlServer:IsTemporal", true)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalHistoryTableName", "CommentsHistory")
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalHistoryTableSchema", null)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalPeriodEndColumnName", "PeriodEnd")
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalPeriodStartColumnName", "PeriodStart");

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
        name: "PeriodEnd",
        table: "Comments",
        type: "datetime2",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified))
        .Annotation("SqlServer:IsTemporal", true)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalPeriodEndColumnName", "PeriodEnd")
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalPeriodStartColumnName", "PeriodStart");

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
        name: "PeriodStart",
        table: "Comments",
        type: "datetime2",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified))
        .Annotation("SqlServer:IsTemporal", true)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalPeriodEndColumnName", "PeriodEnd")
        .Annotation("SqlServer:TemporalPeriodStartColumnName", "PeriodStart");
}
```

Creating a custom conversion should fix this as described below:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Comment>()
    .ToTable("Comments", tb => tb.IsTemporal(temp =>
    {
        temp.UseHistoryTable("Comments", "History");
        temp.HasPeriodStart("SysStartTime");
        temp.HasPeriodEnd("SysEndTime");
    }));
```

https://coderedirect.com/questions/540979/how-can-i-use-system-versioned-temporal-table-with-entity-framework

However when doing it like this I get the following error on `Add-Migration` command:

> Period property 'Comment.SysStartTime' must be a shadow property.

To verify there was nothing wrong with any other code I had I reverted to:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Comment>()
    .ToTable("Comments", b => b.IsTemporal());
```

And then added `public DateTime PeriodStart { get; set; }` to `Comment`.

I then received the error:

> Period property 'Comment.PeriodStart' must be a shadow property.

Is there any way to get around this? We use our `SysStartTime` as a last modified/last updated value and it works really well. Having to include it via `EF.Property<DateTime>(comment, "SysStartTime"))` seems very unnecessary since the column is present both in temporal table and the original table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible to fix in `EF Core 6.0`.

From @ajcvickers, Engineering manager for Entity Framework:

> Unfortunately, there isn't any workaround for this that allows both
> the use of the new temporal table features, and mapping the period
> columns to non-shadow properties.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26960#issuecomment-991867756

Vote below if you want to see this feature in `EF Core 7.0`:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26463

For new entities using SQL Server temporal tables with EF Core we do use `IsTemporal()` so that we can use the built in support for querying historical data.

However instead of specifying a table name like this `ToTable("Customers")`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Customer>()
        .ToTable("Customers", b => b.IsTemporal());
}
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/

We simply set it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal());
```

In order to not bloat `OnModelCreating` if you have a lot of entities a private method can be used like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    SetTemportalTables(modelBuilder);
}
        
private void SetTemportalTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal());
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal());
    modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>().ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal());
}
```

If you want every entity that implements an interface like `IEntity` to have SQL Server temporal tables we solved it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if (property.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEntity)))
        {
            property.SetIsTemporal(true);
        }
    }
}
```